# For the Python library parsedatetime, what do the trailing return values mean?

Tags: python-3.x, package

For example,

`import parsedatetime
p = parsedatetime.Calendar()
p.parse("on December 15th")`

will return

`(time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=15, tm_hour=13, tm_min=41, tm_sec=47, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=11, tm_isdst=0), 1)`

I'm mainly wondering what `tm_wday`, `tm_yday`, `tm_isdst`, and the final number behind the comma (in this case `1` mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those fields of `time.struct_time` simply mean:

- `tm_wday`: the day of the week (Monday is 0)
- `tm_yday`: the day of the year (1st of January is 1)
- `tm_isdst`: whether daylight saving time (DST) is in effect (1), not in effect (0) or unknown (-1)

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html#time.struct_time) for details.

The `parse` method of the `Calendar` class of `parsedatetime` returns a tuple of 2 elements: a `struct_time` and a parse status (the 1 after the comma, in your case). The status tells you whether `parse` found:

- `0`: nothing
- `1`: a date
- `2`: a time
- `3`: a datetime

See the [documentation](https://bear.im/code/parsedatetime/docs/parsedatetime.Calendar-class.html#parse) for details.

Well, OK, the documentation is somewhat incomplete, so I had to find out the rest. Here it is:

`Calendar.parse()` has an optional second parameter, a `struct_time` which
it calls `sourceTime`, that is used as a starting point for the returned
`struct_time`. If the `sourceTime` is not provided, it is constructed from the time of the call.

The “funny” part is, only some fields of the `sourceTime` are changed by
the `parse` method, and which fields are changed depends on the parse status. And, most confusingly, `tm_wday`, `tm_yday`, `tm_isdst` are never
changed!

If the parse status is

- `0`, no field is changed
- `1`, only `tm_year`, `tm_mon` and `tm_mday` are changed
- `2`, only `tm_hour`, `tm_min` and `tm_sec` are changed
- `3`, only `tm_year`, `tm_mon`, `tm_mday`, `tm_hour`, `tm_min` and `tm_sec` are changed

So by your output, I can see that you made the call on Saturday January 11 at 1:41:47 pm.

Comment: Got it, got it – but now I'm confused why I got:
`tm_wday=5, tm_yday=11`
when December 15th is a Tuesday, and definitely not the 11th day of the month?

Comment: Interesting question, I will have to dive deeper into that.

Comment: OK, I found out... Quite weird! No wonder people usually extract the meaningful values from the `struct_time` and leave the rest alone...

Comment: Interesting! Is there a function that would separately have a better way to return the day of the week from the main info from `parsedatetime`?

Comment: Also, wondered if you happened to have any insights into this as well, a separate question about `parsedatetime` I posted on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708073/after-using-parsedatetime-to-get-a-time-structure-from-the-input-string-how-doe