# After using parsedatetime to get a time structure from the input string, how does one slice the rest of the string out?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I'm wondering how to use `parsedatetime` for Python to return both the timestruct and the rest of the input string with just the date/time input removed.

Example:

```
import parsedatetime
p = parsedatetime.Calendar()
p.parse("Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney at 2 pm")
```

returns:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=13, tm_min=9, tm_sec=59, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=12, tm_isdst=0), 0)
```

but I'd also like it to return:

```
"Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney"
```

Is there a way to do that with `parsedatetime`, or would it require a different Python package?

P.S.

I promise this has a practical application, we're using it to build this: [magical.app](https://magical.app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only method of `Calendar` that returns that info is [`nlp()`](https://bear.im/code/parsedatetime/docs/parsedatetime.Calendar-class.html#nlp) (which I suppose stands for Natural Language Processing). Here is a function returning all parts of the input:

```
import parsedatetime

calendar = parsedatetime.Calendar()

def parse(string, source_time = None):
    ret = []
    parsed_parts = calendar.nlp(string, source_time)
    if parsed_parts:
        last_stop = 0
        for part in parsed_parts:
            dt, status, start, stop, segment = part
            if start > last_stop:
                ret.append((None, 0, string[last_stop:start]))
            ret.append((dt, status, segment))
            last_stop = stop
        if len(string) > last_stop:
            ret.append((None, 0, string[last_stop:]))
    return ret

for s in ("Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow at 2 pm to 4 pm!",
          "Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow starting at 2 pm to 4 pm!",
          "Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow starting at 3 pm to 5 pm!"):
    print()
    print(s)
    result = parse(s)
    for part in result:
        print(part)
```

Output:

```
Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow at 2 pm to 4 pm!
(None, 0, 'Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 16, 0), 3, 'tomorrow at 2 pm to 4 pm')
(None, 0, '!')

Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow starting at 2 pm to 4 pm!
(None, 0, 'Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 9, 0), 1, 'tomorrow')
(None, 0, ' starting ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 16, 0), 2, 'at 2 pm to 4 pm')
(None, 0, '!')

Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow starting at 3 pm to 5 pm!
(None, 0, 'Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 9, 0), 1, 'tomorrow')
(None, 0, ' starting ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 15, 0), 2, 'at 3 pm')
(None, 0, ' to ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 17, 0), 2, '5 pm')
(None, 0, '!')
```

The `status` tells you whether the associated `datetime` is actually a date (`1`), a time (`2`), a datetime (`3`) or neither (`0`). In the first two cases, the missing fields are taken from the `source_time`, or from the current time if that is `None`.

But if you examine the output closely, you will see that there is a reliability problem here. Only the third parse can be used, in the other two cases information has been lost. Furthermore, I have no idea why the second and third string would be parsed differently.

An alternative library is [`dateparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#). It looks more powerful, but has its own problems. The `dateparser.parse.search_dates()` function comes close to what you are interested in, but I haven't been able to find out how to tell whether a parsed `datetime` conveys only date information, only time information, or both. Anyway, here is a function that uses `search_dates()` to yield an output similar to the above, but without the `status` of each part:

```
from dateparser.search import search_dates

def parse(string: str):
    ret = []
    parsed_parts = search_dates(string)
    if parsed_parts:
        last_stop = 0
        for part in parsed_parts:
            segment, dt = part
            start = string.find(segment, last_stop)
            stop = start + len(segment)
            if start > last_stop:
                ret.append((None, string[last_stop:start]))
            ret.append((dt, segment))
            last_stop = stop
        if len(string) > last_stop:
            ret.append((None, string[last_stop:]))
    return ret


for s in ("Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow at 2 pm to 4 pm!",
          "Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow starting at 2 pm to 4 pm!",
          "Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow starting at 3 pm to 5 pm!"):
    print()
    print(s)
    result = parse(s)
    for part in result:
        print(part)
```

Output:

```
Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow at 2 pm to 4 pm!
(None, 'Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 14, 0), 'tomorrow at 2 pm')
(None, ' to ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 13, 16, 0), '4 pm')
(None, '!')

Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow starting at 2 pm to 4 pm!
(None, 'Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 0, 43, 0, 726130), 'tomorrow')
(None, ' starting ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 13, 14, 0), 'at 2 pm')
(None, ' to ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 13, 16, 0), '4 pm')
(None, '!')

Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow starting at 3 pm to 5 pm!
(None, 'Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 0, 43, 0, 784468), 'tomorrow')
(None, ' starting ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 13, 15, 0), 'at 3 pm')
(None, ' to ')
(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 13, 17, 0), '5 pm')
(None, '!')
```

I think that searching for the substring in the input is acceptable, and the parsing seems more predictable, but not knowing how to interpret each `datetime` is a problem.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726449/how-to-determine-whether-dateparser-search-search-dates-returns-dates-times

Comment: I've done some more searching and found a couple that I think are more powerful called dateutil: https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil
& timefhuman: https://github.com/alvinwan/timefhuman

It seems to do well with most of the examples I can think of, but each solution has its own issues

Comment: sutime seems to be by far the most powerful one out of the bunch, but is actually quite difficult to configure for the first time. I'm running into a lot of errors simply following their instructions in the documentation

Comment: I'm actually having a good deal of trouble with the initial installation for sutime. The main issue arises here:
`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=./jars`
When I run that, terminal returns:
`zsh: command not found: mvn`

I've installed Maven and added it to path with no luck :(

Comment: are you on a Mac? If yes, you should `brew install maven`, which should take care of paths and everything (I'm on a Mac with maven, only I have bash instead of zsh)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205970/discussion-between-hojung-kim-and-walter-tross).