# How to determine whether dateparser.search.search_dates() returns dates, times, or datetimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, dateparser

Trying to answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708073/after-using-parsedatetime-to-get-a-time-structure-from-the-input-string-how-doe) I stumbled over the following problem:

[`dateparser.search.search_dates()`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#dateparser.search.search_dates) returns a list of tuples, each tuple consisting of a text segment recognized as carrying date and/or time information, and the corresponding `datetime` (plus an optional language code, if requested).

If the segment was of date type, only the date fields of the `datetime` are set. The others are taken from the current time, or from a base datetime that can be supplied via the `settings` parameter. Vice versa if the segment was of time type. Only if the segment carried both date and time information, all the date and time fields of the `datetime` are set.

☞ I have found no way to tell which fields of the `datetime` have been set and which not. ☜

I might supply a particular base `datetime`, and check which field group has changed, but relative dates would be offset from this base, not to mention other problems.

What am I missing? How to tell dates, times and datetimes apart?

Example code:

```
for s in ("Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow at 2 pm to 4 pm!",
          "Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow starting at 2 pm to 4 pm!"):
    print()
    print(s)
    for part in search_dates(s):
        print(part)
```

Output:

```
Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow at 2 pm to 4 pm!
('tomorrow at 2 pm', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 14, 0))
('4 pm', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 16, 0))

Soccer with @homies at Payne Whitney tomorrow starting at 2 pm to 4 pm!
('tomorrow', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 13, 31, 40, 681832))
('at 2 pm', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 14, 0))
('4 pm', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 16, 0))
```